# how to print boost multiprecision 128 bit unsigned integer

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multiprecision

I want to print integer value that converted from hexadecimal value but i only could print hexadecimal value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
using namespace boost::multiprecision;

    cpp_int          dsa("0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF");
    cpp_int          daa("9223372036854775807");
    daa = ((daa * 64) + daa);
    cout << std::hex<<dsa <<std::showbase<< endl;
    cout <<dsa << endl;
    cout <<daa << endl;
    cout <<(int)daa << endl;
    cout <<(int128_t)daa << endl;
```

output

```
ffffffffffffffff
0xffffffffffffffff
0x207fffffffffffffbf
0x7fffffff
0x207fffffffffffffbf
```

How can i print max value of 128 bit type of integer ?

Comment: it worked thanks to ```std::dec``` @rafix07

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `std::numeric_limits` to get the max value, because that's its purpose.
Your formatting issue is independent of your actual question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    auto max = std::numeric_limits<boost::multiprecision::int128_t>::max();
    std::cout << max << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: it says ```expected an identifier  ``` about ```max()``` @lars

Comment: Then you did something wrong or use an old compiler.
Here you can check, that the example compiles.
https://godbolt.org/z/vHxGfZ

Comment: I use microsoft compiler maybe it could be a problem @lars

Comment: Copy the exact error message and compiler version. Otherwise no one will be able to help u

Comment: You needed std::dec only because you used std::hex previously. std::cout is stateful. So your issue was actually not what you asked for ;)
"How can i print max value of 128 bit type of integer ?"

But you should really use numeric_limits to get the max value, because that's its purpose.

Comment: "But you should really use numeric_limits to get the max value, because that's its purpose." should be part of the answer. In my opinion it therefore ins not self explaining.